# Git merge with 'forget ours'

Tags: git

I have a git history like:

```
A - B - C (master)
    \
     D - E (feature)
```

I need to totally ignore commit C. So I need merge with history:

```
A - B - C    E' (master)
    \       /
     D --- E    (feature)
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Why do you need to create `E'` commit? Without it you can just force push master to E (push force is necessary assuming that you need to drop C completely; otherwise reverting C would be a better strategy).

Comment: Commit C is already in 'origin' repository and present on all copies. Whole team had pulled that commit and hten we found it was bad commit (bad merge commit actually), so we need easy way to forget it without troubles. 
As I understand reverting is not good idea then.

Comment: Why exactly reverting is a bad idea? You'll have a commit 'D' that basically has the same file snapshot as 'B', but you won't have to deal with all sorts of pain of rewritten repository history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `revert` the commit.

```
git revert <commit-hash-of-c>
```

This creates a new commit without changes of C. This can be pushed then to the central repository.

```
A - B - C
git revert <hash-of-C>
A - B - C - C' -- equivalent of -- A - B
```